# Easy way of calling function with unknown args count via pointer

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I have the following code:

```
typedef void * (__stdcall * call_generic)(...);
typedef void * (__stdcall * call_push2)(unsigned long,unsigned long);

void * pfunc;
// assume pfunc is a valid pointer to external function

// this is a logically correct way of calling, however this includes:
// add esp, 8
// after the call, and that breaks my stack.
((call_generic)pfunc)(1,1);

// however, if i use this call:
((call_push2)pfunc)(1,1);
// this does not happen and code works properly.
```

It's a pain to track all the calls and count args manually (there are lots of such calls ahead), I'd prefer a macro or something for this, but with that bug it's not possible.

Is there a solution? Is there another way of creating `call_generic` type to do such things?

I do not really understand why exactly it does that "cleanup" but that breaks my stack badly, causing previously defined variables to be lost.

Comment: in standard C++ `void*` can't be a function pointer.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve here? This seems like an awful kludge.

Comment: I'm using microsoft C compiler (cl), and it works, awoodland

Comment: problem is that of I need to call external functions via pointers, but I don't really want to look up every function and rewrite already existing code with correct args count, I'd like a generic macro or something to make that the simple way.

Comment: @einclude: what awoodland means is the C++ standard makes no guarantees that a function pointer will fit into a void pointer (eg: certain member function pointers don't, as they store an object reference)

Comment: Do you have a header file for the external functions?

Comment: @Necrolis: there's no problem with that, the problem is with "add esp" operation after actual "call" instruction.

Comment: @awoodland: Yes, I know all args and definitions for functions being called via pointers, however, I cannot call them directly in my task.

Comment: You could adapt some code I wrote a while back for a similar problem where my goal was typesafety with arbitrary functions where only the header and a shared object were available: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4006/typesafety-with-dlsym-function-loading basically it makes a proxy object that implements operator() to forward to something that was loaded with dlsym()

Comment: I've been told that only correct typedefs for correct functions can help me avoid this, but that's what I'm trying NOT to deal with, that's why I asked this question.

Comment: @einclude: I have a feeling you have compiler warnings turned down, MSVC shouldn't allow you to use `__stdcall` with var args, which means it forcing `__cdecl`, as it should (as that is the **only** way to have variable argument functions)

Comment: @einclude - my solution avoids the typedefs by making proxy objects that infer the types from a declaration

Comment: I guarantee if you manage to find a solution, it will be more error-prone, confusing, and effort than just using the right function signatures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`((call_generic)pfunc)(1,1);` is only a logically correct way of calling if the function pointed to by `pfunc` actually has the signature you cast to, `void *(...)`. Your code tells the compiler to make a varargs call, so it makes a varargs call. A varargs call to a function that isn't a varargs function doesn't work (in this case, there's disagreement who has to clean up the stack, and it gets done twice).

There's no way to do this for free. You must somehow cast the function pointer to the correct signature before calling it, otherwise the calling code doesn't know how to pass the parameters in a way that the callee code can use.

One option is to ensure that all the called functions that `pfunc` might point to have the same signature, then cast to that type. For example, you could make them all varargs functions, although I don't particularly recommend it. It would be more type safe to do what you don't want to - make sure that all the functions that might appear here take two `unsigned long`, and cast to `call_push2`.

Comment: awww, that's what i feared of :(

Answer (score 1):

The trick with `call_generic` won't work with functions that should be called with `__stdcall` calling convention. This is because `__stdcall` implies that the function should clean the stack, OTOH variadic functions (those with `...` arguments) may not do this, since they are not aware of the arguments.

So that marking a variadic function with `__stdcall` calling convention is like shooting yourself in the foot.

In your specific case I'd go in the macro writing direction. I don't see a trivial trick that'd acomplish what you need.

**EDIT**

One of the techniques may be using template classes. For instance:

```
// any __stdcall function returning void taking 2 arguments
template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct FuncCaller_2
{
    typedef void * (__stdcall * FN)(T1, T2);

    static void Call(PVOID pfn, T1 t1, T2 t2)
    {
        ((FN) pfn)(t1, t2);
    }
};

// call your function
FuncCaller_2<int, long>::Call(pfn, 12, 19);
```

You'll need to create such a class for every number of arguments (0, 1, 2, 3, ...).

Needless to say this method is "unsafe" - i.e. there is no compile-time validation of the correctness of the function call.

Answer (score 0):

seems to me you want a form of dynamic function binding mechanism that will bind a pointer to a protoype deducted from an invocation. This generally requires metaprogramming, for this [boost::bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/bind/bind.html) or something else from the boost functions library is your best bet (and if they don't have it, its doubtful that i can be done).

Comment: And it's not straightforward to deduce this function type solely from the invocation, since the function takes two `unsigned long`, but the call site provides two `int`. There would need to be some specific rules to say what an `int` argument expression needs to be converted to - in this example `unsigned long`, but that seems arbitrary. valdo forces the calling side to specify the types, which avoids the need for deduction.

Comment: @Steve: yip, thats the problem with getting too lazy :P